# Change CloudOTP to Random Number in the Firebase Phone Authentication OTP

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sms, message, messaging

I'm facing some issue in the firebase phone authentication OTP sender name means when the user receives the Firebase OTP the Sender Name shows as CloudOTP. More details please check the screenshot.

**Current User Receive OTP with name**

[image: Screen Shot]

**I want to show number like below screenshot.**

[image: Screenshot]

**Question:** How to change sender name?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name or number that is shown with the text message that contains the OTP is determined by the provider and your phone. As far as I know there is no way for you to control that.